# Elixir - Argument error

Tags: elixir

Can someone please help explain why we get the argument error? Are we not supposed to check for truthyness this way? On Elixir 1.3

```
iex(1)> true and true
true
iex(2)> "true"
"true"
iex(3)> true
true
iex(4)> true and "true"
"true"
iex(5)> "true" and true
** (ArgumentError) argument error: "true"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elixir has two sets of boolean operators:

- `or`, `and` and `not` in principle require their arguments to be actual booleans, i.e. the atoms `true` and `false`
- `||`, `&&` and `!` accept arguments of any types, and check "truthiness".

Though in fact, `or` and `and` only check the type of the *first* argument.  For any value of `x`, the expressions `false or x` and `true and x` will simply return `x`.  This might seem confusing, but it allows using `or` and `and` as the last expression in a recursive function without impeding tail recursion.  For example, consider this function, which checks whether all elements in a list are equal to 42:

```
def x([]) do
  true
end
def x([h|t]) do
  h == 42 and x(t)
end
```

Because `and` permits tail recursion, this function will run in constant stack space.  If `and` would check the type of its second argument, the function would have to make a normal call one stack frame "deeper", and upon return perform the check and return the value.

Comment: Thanks for not just explaining why but also the rationale behind it

Answer (score 2):

The "wordy" boolean operators - `and`, `or` and `not` are strict - they expect all values to be strictly boolean. The symbolic operators - `&&`, `||` and `!` - operate on the "truthiness" instead of strict booleans.

Because all booleans operators are short-circuiting they will actually only check the first argument for being strictly boolean, but I discourage using them with non-booleans.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> Elixir also provides three boolean operators: or, and and not. These
>   operators are strict in the sense that they expect a boolean (true or
>   false) as their first argument:
>
> ```
> iex> true and true
> true
> iex> false or is_atom(:example)
> true
> ```
>
> Providing a non-boolean will raise an exception:
>
> ```
> iex> 1 and true
> ** (ArgumentError) argument error: 1
> ```

So that's to answer why it raises.

In order to do what you want, you need to use the `&&` operator, so it would be

```
"true" && true
```

and again, a quote from the docs:

> Besides these boolean operators, Elixir also provides ||, && and !
>   which accept arguments of any type. For these operators, all values
>   except false and nil will evaluate to true:
>
> ```
> # and
> iex> nil && 13
> nil
> iex> true && 17
> 17
> ```